# Reroll Giveaway command not responding when command run?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a discord giveaway reroll command.
The problem is that when the command is run it is not responding/rerolling the giveaway.
I've looked on multiple sites with the same command and all of them did not work/have a fix for this.
I also tried without the embeds to see if that was the problem with the code.
Below is the reroll command code -
(if the giveaway command code is needed I can provide it)

```
    @client.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
    async def reroll(ctx, channel : discord.TextChannel, id_ : int):
        try:
            new_msg = await channel.fetch_message(id_)
        except:
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Command Error ⛔ - GameBot", description=f"**The Id Of A Channel Was Entered Incorrectly!** ", color=0x992d22)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            return
        
        users = await new_msg.reactions[0].users().flatten()
        users.pop(users.index(client.user))

        winner = random.choice(users)

        embed = discord.Embed(title="Giveaways  - GameBot", description=f"**Giveaway Has Been Rerolled!** \n \n**Winner -** \n`{winner.mention}`", color=0xe74c3c)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Below is the giveaway command code -

```
@client.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
    async def giveaway(ctx):
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Giveaway Setup  - GameBot", description=f'**{ctx.author.mention} Giveaway Setup Is Now Starting... Please Answer These Questions Within 30 Seconds!**', color=0xe74c3c)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)

        questions = ["**What Channel Should The Giveaway Be Hosted In?** `EX : #general` ",
                    "**What Is The Duration Of The Giveaway?** `EX : S/M/H/D` ",
                    "**What Is The Giveaway Prize?** `EX : Gift Card` "]

        answers = []

        def check(m):
            return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel

        for i in questions:
            await ctx.send(i)

            try:
                msg = await client.wait_for('message', timeout=30.0, check=check)
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                embed = discord.Embed(title="Command Error ⛔ - GameBot", description=f"**Please Answer All Of The Questions In Time... Be Prepared!** ", color=0x992d22)
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            else:
                answers.append(msg.content)
        
        try:
            c_id = int(answers[0][2:-1])
        except:
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Command Error ⛔ - GameBot", description=f"**Please Provide A Valid Channel For Me To Host The Giveaway In!** `EX : #general` ", color=0x992d22)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            return

        channel = client.get_channel(c_id)

        time = convert(answers[1])
        if time == -1:
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Command Error ⛔ - GameBot", description=f"**The Time Constraint You Answered With Was Not A Valid Unit!** `EX : S/M/H/D` ", color=0x992d22)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            return
        elif time == -2:
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Command Error ⛔ - GameBot", description=f"**The Time Must Include An Integer!** `EX : 1S, 1M, 1H, 1D` ", color=0x992d22)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            return

        prize = answers[2]

        embed = discord.Embed(title="Giveaway Setup  - GameBot", description=f'**Giveaway Channel -** \n`{channel.mention}` \n**Duration -** \n`{answers[1]}`', color=0xe74c3c)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)


        givembed = discord.Embed(title="Giveaways  - GameBot", description=f'**Giveaway Prize/Description -** \n`{prize}`', color=0x2ecc71)

        givembed.add_field(name = "**Host -**", value=ctx.author.mention)

        givembed.set_footer(text = f"Ending {answers[1]} From Now! ")

        my_msg = await channel.send(embed=givembed)


        await my_msg.add_reaction("")


        await asyncio.sleep(time)


        new_msg = await channel.fetch_message(my_msg.id)


        users = await new_msg.reactions[0].users().flatten()
        users.pop(users.index(client.user))

        winner = random.choice(users)

        embed = discord.Embed(title="Giveaways  - GameBot", description=f"**Giveaway Has Ended!** \n \n**Winner -** \n`{winner.mention}` \n**Prize -** \n`{prize}`", color=0xe74c3c)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost everything about the code is correct. However I guess you are requesting the `users` in a wrong/not working way. You can try to request the users in another way, this seems to be the source where the error comes from.

**Try out the following:**

```py
users = [u for u in await new_msg.reactions[0].users().flatten() if u != client.user]

winner = random.choice(users)
```

**The full code would be:**

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def giveaway(ctx):
# Giveaway code


@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def reroll(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel, id_: int):
    try:
        new_msg = await channel.fetch_message(id_)
    except:
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Command Error ⛔ - GameBot",
                              description=f"**The Id Of A Channel Was Entered Incorrectly!** ", color=0x992d22)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        return

    user_list = [u for u in await new_msg.reactions[0].users().flatten() if u != client.user]

    winner = random.choice(user_list)

    embed = discord.Embed(title="Giveaways  - GameBot",
                          description=f"**Giveaway Has Been Rerolled!** \n \n**Winner -** \n`{winner.mention}`",
                          color=0xe74c3c)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: The code you provided did not work and I checked to see if I was writing the command wrong but I wasn't. Thank you for the help though! If I had more than 15 rep I would have upvoted. (The terminal also is not giving me an error)

Comment: Check again, I used `message` instead of `new_msg`. My provided code combined with yours works fine for me.

Comment: I don't know then it is probably just me being dumb and writing the command wrong in discord lol. But thanks for all the help! Ill make sure to try the new code.

Comment: The full code I provided is also not working? I get an output. Also pay attention to the correct indentation.

Comment: Should I send you the code to the giveaway command maybe I need to update something in it to work?

Comment: I guess this could be the problem. Have you tried to react to a normal message and fetch a winner out of that with just the command?

Comment: I am adding the main code for the giveaway command. I am pretty sure I need to add/update something on it.

Comment: Is the normal command working though? I also had no Giveaway embed and just fetched a "winner" out of a normal Discord message where some people reacted.

Comment: Yes, the main giveaway command is working fine it is just that the reroll one isn't doing anything... not even responding to the message. Like I said before could it be that I would need to add changes to the main code?

Comment: Is the command also indented correctly? Have you used `reroll #Channel MessageID` as a command?

Comment: Yes, the command is indented correctly and I have used reroll #channel #messageid but ill try it again to see if it just wasn't working at the time for some reason. edit: It did not work. Can I have an example of the reroll #channel message id just to see if i wrote it wrong?

Comment: If this command also works, there is something wrong with your execution or indentation. Make sure that `client.command` is in the margin and the rest is also correctly indented. Using the command: `!reroll #channel 7289047812934` (Just a random number + prefix)

Comment: Command did not work. I'll start checking for indentation/Spelling errors. If you catch anything else let me know!

Comment: I edited my post to show you how it should be. If you are using PyCharm it should show you how to indent correctly.

Comment: Yep it turned out that at the part where it had the  user_list = [u for u in await new_msg.reactions[0].users().flatten() if u != client.user] i had indented everything under that wrong!

Comment: Thanks for helping me out!. Sorry, I was not able to upvote I do not have 15 reputation yet. Have a great day dude!

Comment: Accepting it as an answer is totally fine. Maybe do not close/delete the post as others could come across the same error and search for help.

Comment: Yes sorry I meant to say accepting it! My fault.